# Unzipping tar.gz file partially

Tags: java, algorithm, io, gzip, compression

Would be possible to unzip tar.gz file partially e.g. unzip only few megabytes from the middle of the large tar.gz file ?

I got this idea as we have a lot zipped log files and it's very time consuming to unzip 100mb log file into ~1gb file and then search in it. Would be great to have option of 'partial unzip'.

Comment: You said you want to unzip some part from your file to search "faster" into it? Even if this is possible how would you know that your info that you're looking for is in that part you unzipped?? Partial unzip is maybe useful when you have for example a currupted file and you want to save the "correct" info

Comment: If you're searching for something, how do you know where in the middle to look?

Comment: You can search by time range - it's log file with timestamps.

Answer (score 5):

Unless the .gz file was specially prepared for this purpose, then no, you need to decompress all of the data up to the middle in order to decompress what's in the middle.

It is possible to use `Z_FULL_FLUSH` in `deflate()` periodically to put breaks in in the compressed data to allow decompression starting at those break points.  You would have to have a different file and your own software to keep track of where those breakpoints were, and how far into the uncompressed data they are.

Since it is a .tar.gz file, it would make sense to only have those breakpoints at file boundaries.  The tar format itself can be read starting at any file header with no problem.